# Is there something similar to online redefenition in sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

In oracle there is something called [online redefenition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN11674).

I am  new to sybase and I am searching for something similar in sybase.

the job of online redefenition is to re-orgnize the space of a table but online, it means it doesnt lock the table.

I read about re-org in [sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1570/html/sag2/X24355.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with SAP ASE 15.7 ESD#2, an online reorg option was added.

```
reorg rebuild <table_name> with online
```

It's documented in the [New Features Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1572/html/new_features/new_features9.htm) for that version.

Be careful, as there is a [known bug affecting ASE 15.7 SP 133 & SP 134](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3741937) that can cause issues with this command.

Comment: Only if you are running one of those specific versions. Otherwise it should be okay.